# How do I use fontsource with React and CSS on CodeSandbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, codesandbox

I have a simple react app where I want to use fontsource on CodeSandbox.

In App.tsx:

```
import "@fontsource/raleway";
import "./styles.css";
```

Then in styles.css:

```
h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

But this is not working.

On Firefox I get this error on console: `downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer`.
On Chrome it also doesn't work with error `Failed to decode downloaded font`.